# How to prevent child component re-rendering in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, components

**How to prevent child component re-rendering in reactjs**

Can anyone help me with giving all possible solution for prevent child component re-rendering while parent component state changes.

I tried to search about it but didn't get any better idea about it. I got an article about it where it is mentioned to use React.memo() but that was without code example and its hard for me as a beginner to understand this concept fully

Comment: Just wrap your componet into `React.memo()` upon export like this `export React.memo(MyComponent)`

Comment: why do you care about rerendering? What problems does it raise in your app?

Comment: If my parent components state changes my child components also re-rendering with the parent components. I dont want this behavior. I want when parent components change child component doesnt need to re-render untill child components state changes.